# Javascript: Hide .div if two inputs have a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two inputs with classes (q1, q2) and a div with class (output). I would like to be able to hide the div when one or all of the inputs have "any value". I'm new to javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.q1, .q2').keyup(function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $('.output').show();
    } else {
      $('.output').hide();
    }
  }).keyup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">Test</div>
<input type="text" value="" class="q1">
<input type="text" value="" class="q2">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check both `input` values to achieve your goal like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.q1, .q2').keyup(function() {
    var q1 = $('.q1').val();
    var q2 = $('.q2').val();

    if (q1.length || q2.length) {
        $('.output').hide();
    } else {
        $('.output').show();
    }
  }).keyup();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output">Test</div>
<input type="text" value="" class="q1">
<input type="text" value="" class="q2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Haseeb has given a great answer.

Just wanted to mention as you're new to JQuery / Javascript it's often worth checking the existence of classes before using them, as it prevents changes to the HTML further down the line causing unexpected issues.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Check if the classes exist here
     if ($(".q1")[0] && $(".q2")[0] ) {
          $('.q1, .q2').keyup(function() {
            var q1 = $('.q1').val();
            var q2 = $('.q2').val();
        
            if (q1.length || q2.length) {
                $('.output').hide();
            } else {
                $('.output').show();
            }
          }).keyup();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You don't really need to check their existence in this case, if q1 and q2 class are not present in the DOM, this function will simply not fire, without causing any issue.

Comment: `if($(".q1")[0])` isn't very clear.   Better stick with tried and tested `if ($(".q1,.q2").length)`.  But, as above, not needed as `$(".q1,.q2").keyup` will only be applied to q1/q2 that already exist at the time, so no need to check - *when adding events* (but other times, this may be good practice)

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, that's helpful to know about .keyup()